# Alternative to implement the momentjs timezone library

Tags: javascript, timezone, dst, momentjs, timezone-offset

I am using the momentjs and moment timezone libraries. I am using them on a server that does not have a module system and no window object. I am thinking that the following code below needs to change in the timezone library, however, I'm not sure how to make it work. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
     define("moment-timezone", ["moment"], onload);
  } 
  else if (typeof module !== 'undefined') {
     module.exports = onload(require('moment'));
  } 
  else if (typeof window !== "undefined" && window.moment) {
     onload(window.moment);
  }
```

I would like to do something like the following, but the server logs tell me that

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'add' of undefined ( @ 1 : 10 ) -> moment.tz.add({
```

```
    moment.tz.add({
        "zones": {
            "America/Los_Angeles": [
                "-7:52:58 - LMT 1883_10_18_12_7_2 -7:52:58",
                "-8 US P%sT 1946 -8",
                "-8 CA P%sT 1967 -8",
                "-8 US P%sT"
            ]
        },
        "rules": {
            "US": [
                "1918 1919 2 0 8 2 0 1 D",
                "1918 1919 9 0 8 2 0 0 S",
                "1942 1942 1 9 7 2 0 1 W",
                "1945 1945 7 14 7 23 1 1 P",
                "1945 1945 8 30 7 2 0 0 S",
                "1967 2006 9 0 8 2 0 0 S",
                "1967 1973 3 0 8 2 0 1 D",
                "1974 1974 0 6 7 2 0 1 D",
                "1975 1975 1 23 7 2 0 1 D",
                "1976 1986 3 0 8 2 0 1 D",
                "1987 2006 3 1 0 2 0 1 D",
                "2007 9999 2 8 0 2 0 1 D",
                "2007 9999 10 1 0 2 0 0 S"
            ],
            "CA": [
                "1948 1948 2 14 7 2 0 1 D",
                "1949 1949 0 1 7 2 0 0 S",
                "1950 1966 3 0 8 2 0 1 D",
                "1950 1961 8 0 8 2 0 0 S",
                "1962 1966 9 0 8 2 0 0 S"
            ]
        },
        "links": {}
    });

    var s = moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format("h:mm a");
```

Comment: Then what kind of runtime are you using?

Comment: I'm using a third party called Apperyio. I believe they use Node.js in the background, but I'm not 100% sure

Comment: Have you tried all of the options shown [in the moment docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/) and [in the moment-timezone docs](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/use-it/)?

Comment: Well I can't install anything on the server. The only thing I can do is write Javascript and it will be executed as server side logic. I can add Javascript libraries - which is what I'm trying to do but it's not working as described above

Comment: running into a similar issue using alpine linux... :/ weird